# Dynamically setting xAxis rotation in high charts API

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Using the below option in Chart I am able to set label rotation angle for Xaxis,

```
xAxis: {
    labels: {
        rotation: 90
    }
},
```

I would like to change the xAxis rotation dynamically(say on a button click for a particular chart type). Is there any option to do that?

Comment: try asking the same on http://highslide.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=9. you'll get a faster response there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this, I am not sure that it will work.

```
chart.xAxis[0].options.labels.rotation = 0;
chart.redraw();
```

Comment: @Pragnesh Patel this post is quite old, it was using highcharts 2.1.4, if you are using a newer one check the current documentation

Comment: Thanks @Elzo. i have gone through documentation and it is same. actually i can debug & see the updated value in chart object still it draws with default values.

Answer (score 4):

This is working for me :

```
chart.xAxis[0].update({labels:{rotation:rotationValue}});
```